# How to set up a user in phpMyAdmin and MySQL and query from NodeJS

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have to set up a small demonstration of NodeJS pulling some data from a MySQL database for my work. I am completely new to NodeJS and MySQL and have just been following tutorials and it has worked fine on localhost and I was able to pull data from the DB. But now I have to access the DB over the internet and it tells me "Error: connect ETIMEDOUT" every single time. I have set up about 10 users in the phpMyAdmin webinterface with different privileges, hostnames and so on but nothing worked yet.

This is my code:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

const sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id >= 12";



var sqlconnection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "2.205.169.200",
    user: "sqltest",
    password: "",
    database: "test_db"
});


sqlconnection.connect(function(error) {
    if(!!error) {
        console.log("Connection " + error);
        return;
    }
    else {
        console.log("CONNECTED SUCCESSFULLY");
    }
});

sqlconnection.query(sqlquery, function(error, rows) {
    if(!!error) {
        console.log("Query " + error);
        return;
    }
    else {
        var result = JSON.stringify(rows, null, 4);
        console.log("QUERY BEGIN -->");
        console.log(result);
        console.log("<-- QUERY END");
    }
});
```

This is the current phpMyAdmin user:
[image: This is the current phpMyAdmin user]

Comment: I think the problem is at your server end, `ETIMEDOUT` error is thrown by nodejs when its unable to get response from server. Check the accessibility of your server. Try to connect with it using `mysql workbench` or any other tool.

Comment: @Shaharyar you're right, my server doesn't seem to be set up correctly. I tried to connect with the MySQL Workbench but it doesn't want to. Somewhere I've read that I can't add users with the phpMyAdmin webinterface. Is that maybe the problem?

Comment: No, there is no problem like that. You can add users from phpmyadmin interface. However you need to check, are you creating `mysql` user or `phpmyadmin` panel user? Both are different.

Comment: I am creating a user in the phpMyAdmin panel